# Can I use "innovate" as a transitive verb?

Tags: grammar, transitive-verbs, style-manuals

For example, is it OK to say: "We're innovating our device"?
Or would I have to say something like "We're innovating in order to change our device"?

Comment: No. _Innovate_ is intransitive. Possibly _invent_ is the verb you want; it's transitive.

Comment: @JohnLawler - innovate is both transitive and intransitive. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/innovate - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innovate - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innovate

Comment: 'Can' in what sense of *can*? Obviously it is physically possible to use it in this way, and you won't be arrested if you do. Do some people use it this way? Yes. Will you be understood if you so use it? Yes. Will such use of it be regarded as an example of a good writing style, by those who care about such matters? No.

Answer (score 1):

Innovate is a transitive verb. Ref: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innovate

The new manager innovated the process. AV
The process was innovated by the new manager. PV

Comment: Innovation at work. _Innovate_ has innovated transitivity. It still sounds like business jargon for "making it up as we go along cuz we don't have a clue". Online dictionaries notwithstanding.